# PDO: Return 0 if query finds no results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm counting total number of records from a column with mysql with php. I want to return zero if no record is found but i keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not
>   exist: `character varying LINE 1: SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(`school_name`),
>   'follow')`answer` as s... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name
>   and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.' in

SQL

```
$row = $conn->query("SELECT IFNULL(Count(school_name), '0') as school_total from schools_tbl");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$school_count = $row->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: I don’t think that message comes from [tag:mysql], now does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SELECT IFNULL in PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245134/how-to-use-select-ifnull-in-pdo)